How can I send a list to an API with AWS step function
I'm creating an AWS step function that makes a request to an API.
I'm trying to send a list that I retrieved from dynamoDB to an api that receives it. however, when I am sending the array it is going in an incorrect format with the dynamoDB structure.
 "informacoes": [
            {
                "M": {
                    "chave": {
                        "S": "LSJ33"
                    },
                    "valor": {
                        "N": "39"
                    },
                    "numero": {
                        "S": "22BRQ"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

I would like send to my api it:
 "informacoes": [
        {          
                "chave": "LSJ33",
                "valor": "39",
                "numero": "22BRQ"                        
        }
    ]

Does anyone know any way I can fix this?

You would need to pre-process the data received from dynamodb as it usually returns data along with datatype, M representing Map here.
You could integrate a lambda in your step function as a new state and input the dynamodb data in it to pre-process it.
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
informacoes = event['informacoes']

# Transform the DynamoDB format to the desired format
transformed_informacoes = []
for info in informacoes:
    transformed_info = {
        "chave": info['M']['chave']['S'],
        "valor": info['M']['valor']['N'],
        "numero": info['M']['numero']['S']
    }
    transformed_informacoes.append(transformed_info)

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps({'informacoes': transformed_informacoes})
}

